# Server 2016 DHCP vs Router DHCP or Both

Tags: router, home-networking, dhcp, windows-server-2016, dhcp-server

I'm running Server 2016 in a home environment and until recently installing Active Directory (I did not install DHCP server) to the server my router has been my DHCP server. Now that I have installed AD and want to use it to manage some children’s laptops I've come into a bit of a problem, and I'm not positive of the source or the solution.

I have joined the laptop to the domain that I wish to manage and when I tried to add a GPO to manage the laptop registry the browser cannot find the laptop. I ping the server from the laptop by hostname and it returns fine, but when I ping the laptop from my server (IP or hostname) the server can't ping it.

I am thinking this is due to how I have everything setup:
In my router I have the DHCP server pool set from 192.168.1.2 through 192.168.1.250
I have my server sitting at 192.168.1.251 (outside of the DHCP pool)

I did this with the original plan of managing parental controls via OpenDNS and time scheduling for the windows laptops and game consoles and other devices.

To be clear there is only 1 server that is the Active Directory & Domain Controller and currently 1 Windows 10 Pro laptop (the others will come once I've figured out the process)

My question:
What would be the best approach to still use the router to manage all other non-Windows devices and use the server to manage the Windows PC's?

Comment: It was the WIndows Firewall on the laptop preventing the connection. What do I need to allow through the firewall so I can have it on and still work the way I need?

Comment: Well this issue initially started when I tried to apply a GPO Registry item. It reaches out to the target pc to get the registry information. I already had the laptop setup with the registry service started and to allow on demand requests via:
sc config remoteregistry start= demand
And
net start remoteregistry

So really I need to be able to reach out from the server to the laptop for administrative purposes, which will largely revolve around GPO I would assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Manage DHCP

You can allow **Windows** to manage the DHCP assignments and disable DHCP in your router unless you have separate subnets you want to allow to use the Internet from that router but not be on the same subnet as the AD network subnet.

The domain controller can handle spitting out DHCP requests just fine to non-domain joined machines that request one. If you have just the one subnet then you likely want the domain controller to manage the DHCP but you can certainly allow the router to handle other subnets or segregated access points, etc. so that really just depends.

---

### What's Blocking Ping

As far as the blocked ping response goes, that's likely due to the **Windows Firewall** blocking that traffic on the laptop. To confirm this is the issue, simply disable the Windows Firewall and then test the ping. If the ping works with it disabled, then you'll know that is what is blocking it.

---

### Allowing Remote Registry Access

From **Run** type in `wf.msc` and press **Enter**. Then go to **Inbound Rules** and test by opening up both `Domain` and `Private` from the **Profile** column of these rules listed below so set those to **Enable** those and **Allow**.  Just be sure to not allow on `Public` classified network scope.

```
Windows Management Instrumentation (DCOM-In)
Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-In)
Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI-Out)
Windows Management Instrumentation (ASync-In)
Network Discovery (SSDP-In)
Network Discovery (SSDP-Out)
Network Discovery (UPnPHost-Out)
Network Discovery (WSD-In)
Network Discovery (WSD-Out)
Network Discovery (LLMNR-UDP-In)
Network Discovery (LLMNR-UDP-Out)
Network Discovery (Pub-WSD-In)
Network Discovery (Pub WSD-Out)
Network Discovery (WSD Events-Out)
Network Discovery (WSD Events-In)
Network Discovery (WSD EventsSecure-Out)
Network Discovery (WSD EventsSecure-In)
Network Discovery (NB-Datagram-Out)
Network Discovery (NB-Datagram-In)
Network Discovery (NB-Name-Out)
Network Discovery (NB-Name-In)
Network Discovery (UPnP-Out)
Network Discovery (UPnP-In)
Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)
Windows Remote Management - Compatibility Mode (HTTP-In)
```

> **Note:** You likely only need to open up the `WMI` rules for the Remote Registry access but you can test one by one to verify this for 100% certainty if you want with the service started.

---

### Further Resources

- [Understanding Firewall Profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/getting-started-wfas-firewall-profiles-ipsec(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [Firewall Rule Properties Page: Scope Tab](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771905(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Also a reason for not being able to ping (ICMP) the desktop is that the Network Sharing is turned off on the desktop.